# How to add function to this button

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

The button will only accept "$dismiss()". But I need it to accept any other function.

````
          var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            animation: this.animationsEnabled,
            ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
            ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
            template: [
                '<div class="modal-content">',
                '<div class="modal-header">',
                '<h3 class="modal-title">Regulamin</h3>',
                '</div>',
                '<div class="modal-body">',
                '$1. Give us all your money!',
                '</div>',
                '<div class="modal-footer">',
                '<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="$ctrl.testing()">TESTING</button>',
                '</div>',
                '</div>'
              ].join(''),
            size: 'md'
          });
        };```
````

Answer (score 0):

**The Example:**
You can see this plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/joQzMkafiDAgsjt0
working with one counter in the parent and increasing through one modal button, it is an example for your need.

**The Issue:**
I would say the missing part is the scope or controller.

**The Explanation:**
When you create a modal it has its own controller and it cannot access its parent scope. You have to refer to the specific functions which you need.

We can include the `controller` parameter to the `$uibModal.open()` and include all the extra information which we need. It'd look like:

```js
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
  animation: this.animationsEnabled,
  ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
  ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
  template: [
    'YOUR TEMPLATE',
    '<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="$ctrl.testing()">TESTING</button>',
  ].join(''),
  size: 'md', 
  // THE NEW PART:
  controller: function($scope) {
    // Option 0: Regular version
    $scope.testing2 = $ctrl.testing

    // Option 1: (if you need to do extra stuff)
    $scope.testing = function () {
      console.log('A new cool function');
      $ctrl.testing();   // Your original testing
    }
  }  
});
```